# grant select on a view does not work

Tags: oracle

My oracle database has a user (Lets say SWEET). Inside SWEET schema, i have a table called AUTO_PARTS.

Now, i created a new user (SWEET_CV) and created a view on SWEET's AUTO_PARTS table.

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION SWEET_CV
   CREATE VIEW SWEET_CV.new_autoparts_view 
      AS SELECT * FROM SWIFT.AUTO_PARTS WHERE PRODUCTNAME = 'ABC'
   GRANT select ON SWEET_CV.new_autoparts_view TO SWEET;
```

The last Grant statement gave error ORA-01720: grant option does not exist for 'SWEET.AUTO_PARTS'. So i did the below.

```
From SWEET account:
GRANT SELECT ON AUTO_PARTS TO SWEET_CV *WITH GRANT OPTION*
And then From SWEET_CV account:
GRANT SELECT ON SWEET_CV.new_autoparts_view TO SWEET;
```

Both the grants succeeded and i committed.

Now, when i login to SWEET and query 'select * from SWEET_CV.new_autoparts_view', rows are returned. But when i query 'select * from new_autoparts_view' it says table or view does not exist. Can you please explain why it says not exist even after i did GRANT.

I want to access the new schema's view in my SWEET without having to refer it as newschema(dot)viewname

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I want to access the new schema's view in my SWEET without having to refer it as*

You need to create a synonym in the `SWEET` schema that references the view:

```
create synonym sweet.new_autoparts_view for sweet_cv.new_autoparts_view;
```

Comment: aaaah.. I knew all along but it did not strike my mind. Totally forgot about synonyms... Thank you